# Cann't Get SourceUrl's attachment from outlook REST API

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365api, outlook-restapi

According to [Outlook Mail REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#get-attachments) I should be able to get 
`SourceUrl` property by calling:

```
`GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/{messageId}/attachments/{attachmentId}`
```

or

```
`GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/{messageId}/?$expand=attachments`
```

in both of version 2.0 and beta but `SourceUrl` is always missing,

do I need any additional information to get it? knowing that I'm not getting any error!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SourceUrl` is only available for referenceAttachments. Meaning, when a file is shared from a cloud location like OneDrive (for Business).

When using normal attachments e.g. from the local drive, the `contentBytes` is available.